# Unable to authenticate Mongodb using MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME in k8s

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I have a problem with creating root user for mongodb deployed in Kubernetes.

Documentation states the following:
#v+
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD

These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.
#v-
But passing those variables to the container does not make it possible to authenticate.

I have included following section in my yaml:

```
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: database-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: admin
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: pass
```

And when I ran kubectl describe the variables were actually there:

```
Containers:
  mongo:
    Container ID:   docker://ef17595eb5da4f096eed09229dcd7426ae1401e9ed773c5e1ac99ff9045d2ecf
    Image:          mongo
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mongo@sha256:8bed0be3e86595283d67836e8d4f3f08916184ea6f2aac7440bda496083ab0c8
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 23 Nov 2022 22:07:28 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  pass
    Mounts:
      /data/db from database-storage (rw)
```

However, when I log onto the pod and try to authenticate, it fails.

```
kc exec -ti pod/database-0 -- mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 637e8c17aa828f64d211fcdb
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
Using MongoDB:      6.0.3
Using Mongosh:      1.6.0

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

test> use admin
switched to db admin
admin> db.auth('admin', 'pass')
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
admin> db.auth(admin, pass)
ReferenceError: admin is not defined
admin> exit
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was also unable to locate a log file that might show what was going on.
The only way I could get a user to initialize was by using a config map mounted to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      name: mongodb-scripts
      readOnly: true.
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      items:
      - key: ensure-users.js
        path: ensure-users.js
      name: mongodb-configmap
    name: mongodb-scripts
```

config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  mongo.conf: |
    storage:
      dbPath: /data/db
  ensure-users.js: |
    const adminDb = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
    adminDb.createUser({user: "test", pwd: "test", roles:[{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase" , db:"admin"}]});
```